# How can I report user profile as inappropriate?

Tags: support, flagging, spam-handling

Is there a way to report a user based on their profile? I found [a user](https://askubuntu.com/users/874968/atlanta-strippers) whose profile description is clearly promoting a strip club as is their profile pic.

I'm looking to report them based on their profile not just on a question they posted. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to what Oli mentioned there is no direct way to report a profile.  The feature was trialed for a bit, but removed. I don't remember why, but I believe there were too many reports for non serious things.

Instead, flag a post that the user has created. Or, if they don't have any posts, posting here on meta works.  You can also drop by [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ping [any of these folks](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) if you see one around.

Comment: There's also the "contact" form in the footer of the site. I've used it in situations like this a few times, and had good results.

Comment: I’ve also seen people on other sites suggest flagging one of your own posts if the user hasn’t posted or any post if you haven’t posted.

Answer (score 8):

You just did it.

Nuked, from orbit. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Using [Oli's favourite tool](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FMjmY.jpg)  **;-)**